# Can I open multiple FileInputStream on single File and use those InputStream to read normally?

Tags: java, file, inputstream

I have a java webapp to return media file when client request. I'm considering the case when there are too many requests to download/retrieve on single file at the same time (ignore problem with connection).
In that case, I will need to open multiple inputstream on the same file at the same time, then read it and return to client.
Is it OK when I try to do that? I mean is there any change that the media is missing data or sth?

Comment: Multiple read will not be an issue, you  can open any no of inputstream on the single file.

Comment: You can read a file by multiple input stream.

Comment: Thank you very much and one more question, will one of those inputstream be blocked? I mean while InputStream A is reading, the remain InputStream will need to be waited until the A is done?

Comment: On any modern file system and Java 1.4+ parallel file reads will be non-blocking and you can open as many FileInputStreams as your system can cope with without crashing or running out of File Descriptors. Each Stream will have its own state. Writing on the other hand will require some form of exclusivity, for hopefully obvious reasons. If you are streaming multiple media files to multiple clients, you will want to consider server side resource usage, but this is unrelated to the actual file IO.

Comment: No. You are in danger of running other file descriptors, but concurrent read-only access to a file is not sequentialized.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul Java 1.4+ has nothing to do with it. Parallel reads do not block each other, and haven't in any computer system I have used since 1979. Java 1.4 did not introduce non-blocking. I/O to files.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, I can't claim to have been alive in 1979, so I wouldn't know ;-) But the 1.4 comment - the version I first got to use - was more meant as a way of underlining "anything you use now won't have that issue"

Comment: Thanks all for helping me, I got it now.